# Variable's type int32_t, int64_t, etc

Tags: c

I have a simple question on the variable's types in C/C++, namely
one can declare such types as

int32_t, int64_t, etc.

My question is what does "t" mean in these types and what's the difference from
the usual types, like int32, int64.

Thanks!

...

Sorry, I don't know how to answer properly to all who responded to my question instead of writing separate comments. Anyway, thanks to all of you for your replies.
Well, I have to say that I am parsing a code and I am a newbie in C/C++ (not C#)

Concerning int32_t etc they seem indeed to be defined separately in a header file:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#ifdef _FAST_
#define SHORT  uint_fast16_t
#define INT    uint_fast32_t
#define LONG   uint_fast64_t
#else
#define SHORT  uint16_t
#define INT    uint32_t
#define LONG   uint64_t
#endif
```

Could someone explain what this construction means?

Comment: Are you sure this is about C#?

Comment: Those sound like custom types, as they're not native to C#.  The "_t" is probably some unnecessary encoding added by whoever created that type because they couldn't think of a better type name.

Comment: http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html

Comment: Its boost integer from cstdint.hpp and its not from c#, maybe you using VC++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no built in types like `Int32_t` and `Int64_t`, and there are no magic suffix `_t` that you can add to an existing type.

The types `Int32_t` and `Int64_t` has to be defined somewhere in your code. They are probably using the `Int32` and `Int64` types in some way, but there is no magic involved just because the type names contains other type names. They could just as well be named `ABigNumber` and `ABiggerNumber` as far as the compiler is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Those look like C++ types (part of Boost's libraries cstdint). In what situation are you seeing these types? Are you using the Boost library?

Edit: I'm guessing the 't' is for 'type' or 'typedef'.